# Updating the editor contents in CodeMirror 6 from Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, codemirror-6

In CodeMirror 5, it is possible for a Selenium test to extract an property called `CodeMirror` on the DOM Element styled with class `CodeMirror`, and call `setValue` on that property to change the editor text but this does not work with CodeMirror 6.

The hierarchy of `DIV`s is very different in CodeMirror 6, with style classes such as `cm-editor`, `cm-theme` and `cm-content`, and attempting to pick off the CodeMirror property returned `undefined`.

Is there an equivalent "way in" to modify the editor contents in CodeMirror 6?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to execute the internals of CodeMirror 6 utility method `EditorView.findFromDOM` using similar logic to the CodeMirror 5 approach of finding a Selenium WebElement by its CSS class and then injecting a function into the page under test that can write to the editor.

Use Selenium calls to locate the WebElement `webElement` with class `cm-content`.

Then the following code can overwrite the contents of the editor with string `"foo"`.

```
webDriver.executeScript(
    "const cm = arguments[0].cmView.rootView.view;\n" +
        'cm.dispatch({ changes: {from: 0, to: cm.state.doc.length, insert: "foo"}});',
    webElement
);
```